# Adding a stored property to a subclass of NSManagedObject in Swift

Tags: cocoa, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

If I try to add a stored property to a subclass in `NSManagedObject` in Swift, without providing it with a default value (I'll do that in an initialiser, mind you), I get this error:

```
Stored property 'foo' requires an initial value or should be @NSManaged
```

The code is as follows:

```
class Thing : NSManagedObject{
    var foo : String
    var bar : String

    init(foo: String, bar : String){

        // blah, blah...
    }
}
```

What's the reason for enforcing this? Why the heck can't I initialise in an initialiser????

Comment: You might use *transient properties* for this purpose. Transient properties are not saved to the persistent store, but Xcode creates the corresponding Swift properties, and the Core Data runtime creates the necessary accessor methods. – Note also that you *must* create managed objects using the designated initializer `init(entity entity: NSEntityDescription,
insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: The below answer applies to a wide variety of situations, and is related for this, but does not exactly address the `NSManagedObject` situation. In the case of `NSManagedObject`, an object can be loaded from the persistent store and initialized without calling your special init. Swift doesn't know what it should assign `foo` and `bar` in those cases, so requires some default values (rather than just using `final` or `required` as you could do in other subclassing situations cases).

So the correct question is: what would you expect Core Data to do with `foo` and `bar` when it loads this object out of the data store?

---

Because the compiler cannot prove that all subclasses will implement or call `init(foo,bar)`. If a subclass did not implement that initializer, then `foo` or `bar` may not be initialized.

You can resolve this many ways. You can provide defaults. You can make the values explicitly unwrapped optionals (making their default `nil`). You can make the values optional. You can declare this initializer `required` so that all subclasses must implement it. Or you can declare `Thing` to be `final` so that it cannot be subclassed.

Comment: And why this only happens when it's a subclass of NSManagedObject? If I remove the super class in the declaration, it compiles fine.